# Is there a way to capture/share only own app screen in Android via WebRTC?

Tags: android, webrtc, screensharing

Based on the AppRTC example I can only share the whole screen on Android, not only my own app [1](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/master/examples/androidapp/src/org/appspot/apprtc/CallActivity.java#472). That is, when my app goes to background the screen sharing does not pause, instead, the other app is shared for example.

Is there a way to only capture a screen of a particular my own app?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I've been struggling for quite a while now

Comment: The solution that we found was to observe the app lifecycle and when the app goes to the background then the screen-sharing streams are paused. And the streams are resumed when the app goes to the foreground. I am not sure if things have changed since then and if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: @OstapMaliuvanchuk hey, can you share the code of how to switch between screen sharing and camera feed and vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. There is already native SDKs that can capture the screen and publish with WebRTC.

[Ant Media Server’s](https://antmedia.io/) Android native SDK framework can do this.

Comment: My question is about capturing and sharing only one app vs sharing the whole screen, not about if screen sharing via WebRTC is possible (which I know it is).

Comment: Hi @Maahi Can you post some code here how to switch between camera and screen sharing using Antmedia? on android. Couldn't get this piece of code.